# Learning SQL - Lost at SQL game

Tags: sql, sqlite

As i am learning the SQL i found games that are good at teaching u it a bit. Im stuck on "Search" challenge at  "Lost at SQL" game.

Anyone can solve this case? im stuck for days on it and banging my head around this

Would really appreciate more advanced people showing me the code so i can analyze and learn on iT:)

https://lost-at-sql.therobinlord.com/challenge-page/search

> Return a table with the columns "path", "diff_total_clicks", and "diff_unique_keywords".

> For each path the table should show the difference in clicks and unique keywords between the most recent 2 days, and the 2 days before.

> Sort the data by change in clicks, in descending order.

I think i am doing something wrong with my JOINS

This where i got the furthest

```
SELECT
  S.path,
  coalesce(sum(clicks) - XDtotal_clicks, sum(clicks)) as diff_total_clicks,
  coalesce(Count(distinct query) - XDunique_query,Count(distinct query))  as diff_unique_keywords

from
  search_data as S
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      path,
      sum(clicks) as XDtotal_clicks,
      Count(distinct query) as XDunique_query
    from
      search_data
    where
      pt < '2022-04-31'
      and pt > '2022-04-29'
    GROUP BY
      path
  ) as XD on XD.path = S.path
where
  pt > '2022-04-31'
GROUP BY
  S.path
```

Comment: Next time, please put the task description into your request, so we don't have to look for it at another site. Always put all the necessary information into your request. And it can help a lot to have some sample data. You can even make a fiddle (e.g. here: https://dbfiddle.uk/) with sample data that we can use to work on your request.

Comment: What is the schema for the table(s)? Please show it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.path,
    (b.total_clicks - a.total_clicks) AS diff_total_clicks,
    (b.unique_keywords - a.unique_keywords) AS diff_unique_keywords
FROM
    (SELECT path, total_clicks, unique_keywords FROM search_data WHERE date = 'most_recent_date') a
JOIN
    (SELECT path, total_clicks, unique_keywords FROM search_data WHERE date = 'most_recent_date_minus_two_days') b
ON a.path = b.path;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  because it doesnt seem to work. From my pov i think there should be a GROUP by clause if we have the aggregate functions here but i checked it and it doesn;t work either

Comment: Sorry mate, this is all I can understand from your question. Maybe you may provide your table schema or some test data to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Each path has a most recent date:

```
select path, max(pt)
from search_data
group by path;
```

You are supposed to select each path's data for its maximum date and the day before and aggregate the data. Then you shall do the same for the two days before and then compare the results.

So, per path we are interested in four days for which we need the path's maximum date. We can get it in an aggregation query as shown above or on-the-fly with a window function: `MAX(pt) OVER (PARTITION BY path)`.

```
with
  data as
  (
    select sd.*, max(pt) over (partition by path) as max_pt
    from search_data sd
  )
select
  path,
  sum(case when pt >= date(max_pt, '-1 day') then clicks else -clicks end)
    as diff_total_clicks,
  count(distinct case when pt >= date(max_pt, '-1 day') then query end) -
  count(distinct case when pt <  date(max_pt, '-1 day') then query end)
    as diff_unique_keywords
from data
where pt >= date(max_pt, '-3 days')
group by path
order by diff_total_clicks desc;
```

Not knowing the tables, I've used the same columns as you did. I hope the query is self-explanatory enough. Using `CASE` expressions in the aggregation function calls is called "conditional aggregation". It helps two work with different aggregations (last two days vs. the two days before them here) at once.

My query does not pass the test. I've tried it and I get the error messages:

> The result is missing 1 expected rows.

> There are 1 incorrect rows in the result.

I don't see how a row can be missing. I group by path and select all rows per path with a pt greater or equal their maximum pt minus three days. So I should at least get the one maximum-pt row per path. Must be something with SQLite's weird date/time handling where there don't exist the proper data types or something along these lines. Unfortunately I don't see the table definition on that site. Nor do we see the selected data and the expected data in order to draw conclusions. Maybe a SQLite pro can help here.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know it is harder than it seems and im learning SQL from a week and seems its not that easy to solve :D Also i didnt include whole table in main post as i thought it's just much easier to enter the game for itself and solve it as it gives u feedback if its right or wrong immediately rather than posting here multiple solution that may or may not work.

Also hope some SQLite Master will sees it and can help with the solution :)